# Google AdMob not showing ad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, admob

I'm trying to add a google Ad and i'm not recieving adds,

```
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       self.view.frame.size.height -
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView.adUnitID = @"XXXXXXXXXXXX";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView.rootViewController = self;
///////////////////////////      

[self.view addSubview:bannerView];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
GADRequest* gadReq = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
[gadReq setTesting:YES];
[bannerView loadRequest:gadReq];
```

what I have done wrong?

Comment: In your actual code you're replacing the ad unit id with the real value, right?

Comment: right, thats what I do, but I don't know somehow its working fine now

Comment: If it is working, then you should close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Implement GADBannerViewDelegate protocol methods to get callbacks from ad request and debug whether you are not receiving ad or your code just cannot show it. See [GADBannerViewDelegate documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios-gadbannerviewdelegate).

Answer (score 0):

Check twice that you type "YOUR PUBLISHER ID" :)
also, check settings in adMob profile for your app.